# How can I convert socket messages into string messages

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Hi guys I start learning python a month ago so excuse me for any stupid mistake. I recently make this chat server and it works find, but the messages that client receive, instead or have the form **Hi, there**, they look like this **b'Hi, there\r\n'**, like a binary message, also because of this the \n and \r dont take effect. I post here my code, so if somebody could help me out it would be great, thanks.
If someone want to test it the clients connect through telnet

```
import socket
import select
class ChatServer:
    def __init__( self, port ):
        self.port = port;
        self.srvsock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
        self.srvsock.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1 )
        self.srvsock.bind( ("", port) )
        self.srvsock.listen( 5 )
        self.descriptors = [self.srvsock]
        print ('ChatServer started on port %s' % port)
    def run( self ):
        while 1:
            # Await an event on a readable socket descriptor
            (sread, swrite, sexc) = select.select( self.descriptors, [], [] )
            # Iterate through the tagged read descriptors
            for sock in sread:
                # Received a connect to the server (listening) socket
                if sock == self.srvsock:
                    self.accept_new_connection()
                else:
                    # Received something on a client socket
                    str = sock.recv(100)
                    # Check to see if the peer socket closed
                    if str == b'exit\r\n':
                        host,port = sock.getpeername()
                        str = 'Client left %s:%s\r\n' % (host, port)
                        self.broadcast_string( str, sock )
                        sock.close
                        self.descriptors.remove(sock)
                    else:
                        host,port = sock.getpeername()
                        newstr = '[%s:%s] %s' % (host, port, str)
                        self.broadcast_string( newstr, sock )

    def broadcast_string( self, str, omit_sock ):
        sms=bytes(str,'utf-8')
        for sock in self.descriptors:
            if sock != self.srvsock and sock != omit_sock:
                sock.send(sms)
        print (str)


    def accept_new_connection( self ):
        newsock, (remhost, remport) = self.srvsock.accept()
        self.descriptors.append( newsock )
        newsock.send(b"You're connected to the Python chatserver, enter 'exit' to get out\r\n")
        str = 'Client joined %s:%s\r\n' % (remhost, remport)
        self.broadcast_string( str, newsock )

myServer = ChatServer( 2626 )
myServer.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the variable `str` is your binary string.

You can convert it in the way you specified like this:

`str = str.decode('utf-8').strip('\r\n')`

If this doesn't work, please tell me!

Comment: I dont understand where do you suggest me to use this, please could you specify me, thanks

Comment: Right before the line that says `host,port = sock.getpeername()` you should put `str = '\r\n'.join(str.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: I might also mention that str is a bad variable name because it overwrites the builtin function str()

Comment: Thanks @Qwery it really help your answer, the chat is working perfectly now, but instead of using  `'\r\n'.join(s.decode('utf-8'))` I use `''.join(s.decode('utf-8'))`, because the way you say me the program put between each sting in str the `\r\n`. But thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @user652704 sorry I was doing it wrong, it should be strip not join, I will edit

Comment: @user652704 I edited the code, try it with the new one, also if this is the correct answer it should be accepted

Comment: I realize that the only I needed was `str = str.decode('utf-8')`. I already accept the answer